# @Configurable support in Java 8 compile time weaving

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Trying to avoid load time weaving and trying to compile time weave aspects in.

I tried approaches here - http://javagalleog.blogspot.de/2016/03/gradle-and-aspectj.html.

But I keep hitting an error warning.

```
[warning] Found @DeclareAnnotation while current release does not support it (see 'org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.AtAjAttributes')
```

So question is - has anybody has tried to do a compile-time weaving on a spring boot application running java 8. Any example project configuration will greatly help.

**Update**
javap -private -verbose  reveals that aspectj weaving might have been successful.

```
 #357 = Fieldref           #71.#356      // <MyClass>.ajc$tjp_5:Lorg/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint$StaticPart;
  #358 = Utf8               org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverVersion
  #359 = Utf8               org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverState
```

However it still wont work - Meaning I wrote a test that SpringBooTest that creates an instance of , but the autowired fields come out as null.  Am I missing any annotation on my configuration class. I only have @SpringBootApplication on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was missing `@EnableSpringConfigured`. Adding that made it work.